# Registro não está sendo enviado ao banco de dados

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, node.js

Quando utilizo 'insert into noticias set ?', para fazer o registro no banco, simplesmente não é registrado
Model:

```
module.exports = function() {
    ...

    this.salvarNoticia = function(noticia, connection, callback) {

        connection.query('insert into noticias set ?', noticia, callback)
    }

    return this;
}
```

admin.js:

```
module.exports = function(application) {
    ...

    application.post('/noticias/salvar', (req, res) => {
        var noticia = req.body; 

        var connection = application.config.dbConnection();

        var noticiasModel = application.app.models.noticiasModel;

        noticiasModel.salvarNoticia(noticia, connection, function(error, result) {
            res.redirect('/noticias');
        })

    })
```

}

Estou utilizando o consign, os dados vindos do formulário estão todos ok, tanto que se eu tentar cadastrar no banco desta forma:

```
connection.query(`insert into noticias(titulo, noticia) values ('${dadoRetornadoDoForm.titulo}', '${dadoRetornadoDoForm.noticia}')`, dadoRetornadoDoForm, callback)
```

O cadastro é feito normalmente, onde está o erro?

Obs: a versão do meu MySQLServer é a 8.0

Comment: Não retornar erro? Eu penso que deve ser a questão do assíncronismo. Transforma o post em uma chamada async e pede para  connection, noticiasmodel e noticias model.salvar esperar. `async/await`.

Comment: Por algum motivo, hoje de manhã eu fui testar novamente e funcionou normal, provavelmente eu devo ter esquecido alguma coisa. :s

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo de como transformar o post em uma chamada async? Este transtorno continua me abusando

Comment: Segue um exemplo de um post `async/await`. Na primeira [IMAGEM 01](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/aws01-jpg) temos  post('/upload') com duas funções em espera, a função `geturl` é dependente da função `upload`, mas para eu pedir para cada uma das funções `await` eu tenho q criar uma função promessa como na segunda [IMAGE 02](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/aws02-jpg).

Comment: Se você me perguntar qual a vantagem de `async/await` em vez de callback, eu diria que o codigo fica muito mais limpo e organizado, fica mais fácil de entender. No caso do seu código teríamos que ver se o seu model pode ser uma promessa, se for sequelize ou mongoose é bem simples para implementar a promessa, o salvarnoticias ja é uma promessa então await já seria suficiente, já que todas as chamadas a banco são promessas.

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que você faça as seguintes alterações no seu código para que, pelo menos um erro seja retornado caso a operação não seja realizada com sucesso. Primeiro altere seu `model` para o seguinte:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const salvarNoticia = async (noticia, conexao) => {
  const query = promisify(conexao.query);

  return query(`INSERT INTO noticias (titulo, noticia) values ('${noticia.titulo}', '${noticia.noticia}')`);
}

module.exports = {
  salvarNoticia,
};
```

O seu `controller` ficará assim:

```
// Faça aqui o require da model que será referenciada depois como "noticiasModel" e da sua conexão que será referenciada com o nome "conexao"

const create = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { body: noticia } = req;
    await noticiasModel.salvarNoticia(noticia, conexao);
    res.redirect('/noticias');
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send('Ocorreu um erro interno.');
  }
}

module.exports = {
  create
};
```

E a chamada da rota será a seguinte:

```
application.post('/noticias/salvar', noticiasController.create);
```

Dessa forma, caso ocorra um erro, o mesmo irá aparecer completamente no `console` do `Node.js` e a requisição irá falhar da forma que é esperada.